# Unable to login inside a Django unittest

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-unittest

How do you simulate logging in to admin inside a Django unittest? The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#overview-and-a-quick-example) make it seems simple, but when I do that, I get 200 response and a page saying "Please log in again, because your session has expired."

My unittest looks like:

```
def test_login(self):

    client = Client()
    user = User.objects.get(username='jondoe')
    user.set_password('password')
    user.save()

    response = self.client.post(
        '/admin/login/',
        {'username': 'jondoe', 'password': 'password'})
    print(response)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue('Please log in again' not in str(response)) # THIS FAILS?!
```

my unittest's Django settings look like:

```
import os, sys

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}
ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.tests.urls'
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.messages',

    'myapp',
    'myapp.tests',
]

SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
USE_TZ = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'

SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

SITE_ID = 1

BASE_SECURE_URL = 'https://localhost'
BASE_URL = 'http://localhost'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your test, you'll either need to load a fixture that has the user data you need or create a new User record, and then you can:

```
client.login(username='your-username', password='your-password')
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.client.Client.login

To facilitate further tests where `client` is needed, I would suggest creating the client instance in the `setUp` method of your `TestCase`:

```
class YourTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
```